# Delete Record in View with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I have created a view in SQL Server using joins. I want to delete a record in the view. Can we delete a record in the view as we delete in the simple table using Entity Framework and which will update the record in the corresponding tables?

Comment: There is no data in the view to delete, the data remains in the underlying tables.

Comment: My suggestion would be to update or delete the record in one of your tables, so that it would not be picked up by the view you created.

Comment: Maybe this [article](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/sqldbauk/2011/07/11/can-you-delete-from-a-view_3F00_/) helps you. Could be possible for views based on only one table, I am not sure how this could be done with EF though.

Comment: thanks for sharing this article nilsK. it really helped.

Comment: If you delete a record from a base table, of course it will be "deleted" from the view. I don't understand your question.